# Disabling all occurance of function/method call in eclipse project

Tags: c, eclipse, comments

i have a C project in eclipse and i want to disable all occurrence of a function call in the project

is it possible to do

```
    file : ref.c
    int refer()
    {
    a = 0;
    }

    file one.c
    int call{
    XXXX
    XXX
    //refer();

    }

    file two.c
    int call1{
    XXXX
    XXX
    //refer();

    }
```

how to achieve the above

Answer (score 1):

You can `#define` it away using:

```
#define refer()
```

Add the line above to a filevincluded in all of the source files.

Alternativly you could add the compiler (pre-processor) option

```
-D'refer()'=
```

to the build command.